# Is there a Ruby equivalent for JavaScript's Function.prototype.bind?

Tags: javascript, ruby

JavaScript happy times fun land

```js
// make a method
var happy = function(a, b, c) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
};

// store method to variable
var b = happy;

// bind a context and some arguments
b.bind(happy, 1, 2, 3);

// call the method without additional arguments
b();
```

Output. Yay!

```
1 2 3
```

---

In Ruby

```rb
# make a method
def sad a, b, c
  puts a, b, c
end

# store method to variable
b = method(:sad)

# i need some way to bind args now
# (this line is an example of what i need)
b.bind(1, 2, 3)

# call the method without passing additional args
b.call
```

Desired output

```
1, 2, 3
```

---

For what it's worth, I know JavaScript can change the context of the binding with the first argument passed to `.bind`. In Ruby, I'd be 99% happy even if I couldn't change the context. I primarily need to simply bind parameters to the method.

**Question**

Is there a way to bind parameters to an instance of a Ruby `Method` such that when I call `method.call` without additional parameters, the bound parameters are still passed to the method?

**Goal**

This is a common JavaScript idiom and I think it would be useful in any language. The goal is to pass a method `M` to a receiver `R` where R does not need (or have) intrinsic knowledge of which (or how many) parameters to send to M when R executes the method.

A JavaScript demonstration of how this might be useful

```js
/* this is our receiver "R" */
var idiot = function(fn) {
  console.log("yes, master;", fn());
};


/* here's a couple method "M" examples */
var calculateSomethingDifficult = function(a, b) {
  return "the sum is " + (a + b);
};

var applyJam = function() {
  return "adding jam to " + this.name;
};

var Item = function Item(name) {
  this.name = name;
};


/* here's how we might use it */
idiot(calculateSomethingDifficult.bind(null, 1, 1));
// => yes master; the sum is 2

idiot(applyJam.bind(new Item("toast")));
// => yes master; adding jam to toast
```

Comment: Your question madam please ? :)

Comment: I'm hardly a reference, but I've never seen Ruby written that way. I'm curious... is there a particular reason for that approach? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mohamad this is a common JavaScript idiom. I added some info to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, rebinding methods isn't something you do in Ruby. Instead, you use blocks:

```
# This is our receiver "R"
def idiot(&block)
  puts("yes, master; #{block.call}")
end


# Here's a couple method "M" examples
def calculateSomethingDifficult(a, b)
  return "the sum is #{a + b}"
end

def applyJam(object)
  return "adding jam to " + object.name
end

class Item
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end


# Here's how we might use it
idiot do
  calculateSomethingDifficult(1, 1)
end
#=> yes master; the sum is 2

# You *can* change calling context too (see instance_exec), but I'd
# discourage it. It's probably better to just pass the object as a
# parameter.
idiot do
  applyJam(Item.new("toast"))
end
#=> yes master; adding jam to toast
```

---

If you really want to "bind" methods like you do in JavaScript it's definitely possible though:

```
class Method
  def bind *args
    Proc.new do |*more|
      self.call *(args + more)
    end
  end
end
```

That should make your example work *almost* as you originally described:

```
# make a method
def sad a, b, c
  puts a, b, c
end

# store method to variable
b = method(:sad)

# Get a "bound" version of the method
b = b.bind(1, 2, 3)

# call the method without passing additional args
b.call
```

If you need it exact, you can probably define `Object#bindable_method` to return some `BindableMethod` class that does what you want. For most cases though I think the above should work for you.

Comment: This would execute the method at the time of binding. The point is to bind parameters to the method but defer the actual calling of the bound method until a later time.

Comment: @naomik No it won't; give it a try! ;) There's one caveat though that I forgot to mention. One second while I edit my answer.

Comment: Oh you're right. You're wrapping the original method with a new Proc. I see now. Hmm... give me a moment to contemplate the implications here...

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I've made a small tweak to make it behave more identically to `Function.prototype.bind`. Check it out: https://gist.github.com/naomik/6368452

Comment: And thank you for the more idiomatic approach in Ruby. This is very helpful

Answer (score 4):

`Proc#curry` in Ruby is similar to `bind` in JavaScript.

```
def happy(a, b, c, d = 100)
  puts a, b, c, d
end

proc = method(:happy).to_proc.curry # proc is now a curried Proc

b = proc.call(1,2) # b is a curried Proc with 1 and 2 bound as the first arguments

b.call(3) # Call the proc, providing the 3rd argument
```

You can't exactly duplicate your example code because when the curried proc is called with the necessary arguments, it returns the result of the proc --- in other words, you cannot bind ALL of the arguments and then call the proc later --- you have to leave at least one argument unbound.

This isn't necessarily a better option than the code provided by Ajedi32, but I think it's worth mentioning because it's built-in to Ruby.

See the docs here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-curry